# catching custom exception in js

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch, throw, custom-exceptions

If I have following

```
function ValidationException(nr, msg){
   this.message = msg;
   this.name = "my exception";
   this.number = nr;
}
function myFunction(dayOfWeek){
   if(dayOfWeek > 7){
      throw new ValidationException(dayOfWeek, "7days only!");
   }
}
```

Question is:
How can I catch this particular exception in catch block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript [does not have a standardized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses) way of catching different types of exceptions; however, you can do a general `catch` and then check the type in the `catch`. For example:

```
try {
    myFunction();
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ValidationException) {
        // statements to handle ValidationException exceptions
    } else {
       // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
       console.log(e); //generic error handling goes here
    }
}
```